# How can i Save two different forms At the same time Using Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Im planning to save 2 forms but the 1st form is where i get the Foreign key for the Second form

This is my Attempt to save this Using Javascript

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#workForm').submit();
        $('#contForm').submit();
    });
```

But it errors on Contact Form Submit in the control because the ID of Worker Form is still null while saving the contact form that is its Foreign Key

How can i Handle This using Jquery and Javascript?

i also Tried this method

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        if (Id != 0) {
            $('#workForm').submit();
            $('#contForm').submit();
        } else {
           $('#workForm').submit(); }
    });
```

But it only go at Else because the ID is null

I hope someone can help me here

Thanks :D
Worker Address is the WorkForm 
Worker Contact is the ContForm

I want to save them both when they populate all the textbox

[image]

Comment: I suggest using `AJAX` to submit the form. Or you might want to wait until the `'#workForm'` form is done submitting so that you can submit `'#contForm'`

Comment: can i see how should i do it @Shawn31313 ?

Comment: I would suggest using one form. Why on earth are you using two?

Comment: why not submit it as one form and then handle the foreign key restraints on the back-end?

Comment: @JanR Question Updated

Comment: @Godwin Question Updated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how my AJAX suggestion would work:

```
$.post("/form1.php", {
  //form data here
}, function (data) { // get data to use in the second form
    $.post("/form2.php", {
      //form data here
    }, function () {

    });
});
```

However, I agree with everyone else to just use 1 form.

How are you originally submitting the forms?

Comment: Hmm, so those posts are not submitted using AJAX right? So when your submit the page refreshes?

Comment: you're Correct , The Page Refreshes when it saves

Comment: Okay, so when the form is submit. Try passing a query trying to the URL like: "?id=123456&posted". When loading the page, use javascript to look for that and if it is found submit the other form.

Comment: I can't think of any other way to do it besides `localStorage` or `cookies`. AJAX is probably the best way to go though.

Comment: Sir they are on the same page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33734/discussion-between-enrique-gil-and-shawn31313)

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly need to use AJAX. With every ajax call you specify response handler function. When response of first AJAX call comes back, you can initiate the save of 2nd form using AJAX.

Now, what do you really do in AJAX call. You should serialize form content into JSON using plugins like form2js or jquery serialize functionality. Then use $.ajax to POST that (note: this is different from regular form submits). In the success response, you need to ensure your server returns necessary information required for submitting 2nd form using AJAX. On getting response, make necessary UI updates, collect information required for 2nd form submission, serialize it and then send it again using another $.ajax.

Following is a rough code structure.

```
function submitForms() {
   var form1Contents = serialize_form1_to_json;
   $.ajax({ 
       url: form1_action_url,
       type: "POST",
       data: form1Contents
   }).done(function (data) {
      //data is the response of first form save from server. should contain the id you need for form 2
      var form2Contents = serialize_form2_to_json;
      set_id and any other details from form1 _on_form2
      $.ajax({
       url: form2_action_url,
       type: "POST",
       data: form2Contents
      }).done(function(){
         alert('both forms saved.');
      });
   });
}
```

NOTE: The forms to be submitted MUST be same domain as the page which contains the form. AJAX is not allowed cross domain due to security issues.